# This allows for the proper sizing of equipment

Tags: gerunds

This allows for **the** proper **sizing** of equipment.

1. What does the sizing here mean? Is it an action or a noun?
2. If it an action, is the use of 'the' correct?
3. If it is ok to use the with an action, then how about "stop the brushing"? (Stop brushing your teeth)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Sizing" is kind of both a verb and a noun here!  "Sizing" is the gerund form of *to size*.   To *size* in this case means **[to make a particular size :  bring to proper or suitable size](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/size)**.  So *sizing* means **the act of making a particular size**.

Because it's a gerund, which is a verb form that acts like a noun, **yes, the use of "the" is correct**, because we're talking about a specific act of making something a particular size, but it isn't necessary.  This particular sentence would have worked fine without it too.

**"Stop the brushing" is gramatically correct, but it doesn't sound like what a native speaker would say.**  A phrase like "the brushing" means a specific, particular act of brushing.  If you want to tell someone to stop an action, it would be more common to say "Stop brushing".  A place where you will see "stop the X-ing" very frequently is in *stop the bleeding*, like "Run cold water over the cut to constrict the blood vessels and stop the bleeding."  This is because in this case, we're concerned with a specific instance of bleeding that's happening right now, and not bleeding in general.

Comment: Thank you. It was easy to understand. Then how about "stop the feigned coughing", talking to someone to stop?

Comment: "Stop the feigned coughing" is grammatically correct, because you're telling someone to stop a particular act of fake coughing, but it doesn't sound like something a native speaker would say.  *Feigned* is a very formal way of saying *fake*, and if you want to emphasize that someone should stop the particular act that they're doing right now, I would say "that" instead of "the".  *Stop that fake coughing* sounds more fluent than *Stop the feigned coughing*.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain the difference between that and the? Doesn't 'the' refer to something specific too?  what governs the each usage?

Comment: That's actually a very good question about a subtle point.  The article *the* means a noun that is unique or known from context (like "the bleeding" = "the one particular example of bleeding we're talking about right now").  *That* is a demonstrative, which is usually used when you're indicating a specific noun, like "My car is old and rusty, but *that* car* is new."  Even more than that, though, in English "**Stop that (behavior)**" is an idiomatic stock phrase meaning "stop doing that particular behavior that you're doing right now".

Comment: Here's a post on the difference between *the* and *that* from English.SE: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6839/difference-between-the-and-that

Answer (score 1):

*Sizing* here is a gerund.  Gerunds aren't verbs, but they are derived and related to verbs.  *Sizing* here in particular is a "verbal" form of *to size* that is functioning as a noun.

*To size X* means the equivalent of either

- to find the size of X, or
- to find something that is a size that will fit X.

*-ing* words in general mean "the action of" - e.g. walking = the action of walking, sizing = the action of sizing.

Since *sizing* along with gerunds in general are nouns, most of the normal rules with articles apply.  One exception is if a gerund has an object, then you don't use an article, e.g. *I got in trouble for him sizing the equipment incorrectly.*

*Sizing* is a definite event that is likely known from previous sentences or conversation, so *the* is called for here, versus *a* or no article.